# How do I add a branch to my repository that is in gitosis

Tags: git, version-control, gitosis

I have successfully setup gitosis on my machine and I have my project safely on the gitosis server.  It currently has no branches (just master).  How do I add a branch to it? (I am not talking about the config of it, I can figure that out, but literally adding a branch)

Do I add a branch in my local repo and push?
Do I do something in gitosis?

Cheers.

Comment: You should probably think about transitioning to using gitolite instead of of gitosis. Gitosis's maintainer seems to have lost interest a while ago, whereas gitolite is actively developed and supported.

Comment: If gitosis does what s/he needs, why switch? It's very unlikely to be broken by anything git does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a local branch with:

```
git branch branch_name
```

and then you tell the remote you have a new branch with:

```
git push origin branch_name
```